# I need to append the elements of one list to a new list based on the values of a third list

Tags: python, list, for-loop, append

Working in python for a class assignment.

I have a list with each element being a sentence with type string.

I have another list with each element being a 1 or 0 based on each sentence of the first list.

So each element sentence has a score of either 1 or 0. I'm trying to create a third list using a for loop

This is the code I was expecting to work and I can't seem to find a better solution online.

```
sentences = ['The house is big','Look at the tree','He is eating food']
scores = [1,0,1]
newlist = []
for i in scores:
    if i == 1:
        newlist.append(sentences[i])
print(newlist)
```

I want my newlist to include ['The house is big', 'He is eating food']

How would I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two solutions come to mind, first you can use `zip` for a more Pythonic approach to iterate over values in both lists simultaneously:

```py
sentences = ["The house is big", "Look at the tree", "He is eating food"]
scores = [1, 0, 1]
new_list = []

for string, score in zip(sentences, scores):
    if score == 1:
        new_list.append(string)

print(new_list)
```

You can also shorten it to a list comprehension (in which case you don't need a `for` loop like above):

```py
new_list = [string for string, score in zip(sentences, scores) if score == 1]
```

Another way could be to use `enumerate` to get the indices you need, because the current issue is that you are trying to access an index that has the same value as the score which is either 1 or 0 so you will always get only the second item from `sentences`:

```py
sentences = ["The house is big", "Look at the tree", "He is eating food"]
scores = [1, 0, 1]
new_list = []

for index, score in enumerate(scores):
    if score == 1:
        new_list.append(sentences[index])

print(new_list)
```

Again, you can use a list comprehension too:

```py
new_list = [sentences[index] for index, score in enumerate(scores) if score == 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looping through scores thus you are doing this:

> Appending `sentence[1]` because `i = 1` in the first iteration
>
> Then appending nothing because `i != 1`
>
> Then appending `sentence[1]` again because `i = 1` on the 3rd
> iteration

You could use `zip` to iterate both iterables at once. Here's an example:

```
new_list = [sentence for i, sentence in zip(scores, sentences) if i == 1]
```